# Conflicts: Spring MVC with Hibernate Validator - Submit/Binding action

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, spring-4, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have two entities, they are: Person and Address, relation one to one. The source code about JPA/Hibernate has been removed to keep the things simple.

My problem is with Hibernate Validator.

I have the following for the **Person** class:

```
@Valid
@NotNull(message="{person.address.null}", groups={AddressCheck.class})
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}
```

and for **Address**:

```
@NotNull(message="{field.null}", groups=AddressCheck.class)
public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}
```

**Note**:
About JUnit, all works fine, if some dependency is null the respective error is created.

The problem is when Hibernate Validator is *integrated* with Spring MVC, it through the **binding** approach

About the view code, below the JSP fragment for the Address class

```
<form:form modelAttribute="person"  method="post" >
...
<fieldset>
    <legend><spring:message code="address.form.legend"/></legend>
    <table>
        <form:hidden path="address.id"/> 
        <tr>
            <td><spring:message code="address.form.street"/></td>
            <td><form:input path="address.street" size="40"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="address.street" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><spring:message code="address.form.number"/></td>
            <td><form:input path="address.number" size="40"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="address.number" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

To create the form view, to let the JSP render both objects, I have the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String createRegisterForm(Model model){
    logger.info("createRegisterForm GET");
    Person person = new Person();
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setId("5");//just to play/test

    person.setAddress(address);
    address.setPerson(person);

    model.addAttribute("person", person);
    return "jsp/person/registerForm";
}
```

Observe how the two setters are called.

When I do the submit the following code must be executed

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerPerson( @Validated(PersonRegistrationOrdered.class) Person person, 
                              BindingResult result,
                              Model model){
    logger.info("registerPerson POST");
    logger.info("{}", person.toString());
    logger.info("{}", person.getAddress().toString());

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        logger.error("There are errors!!!!");
        model.addAttribute("person", person);

        for(ObjectError objectError : result.getAllErrors()){
            logger.error("Error {}", objectError);
        }

        return "jsp/person/registerForm";
    }
    logger.info("All fine!!!!");
    return "jsp/manolo";
}
```

Sadly the console shows an error about the Person object from the Address class is null, even when in the **createRegisterForm** it has been related `address.setPerson(person);`

My unique way to around this is disabling the validation

```
//@NotNull(message="{field.null}", groups=AddressCheck.class)
public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
}
```

**First Question**: how I can avoid this without disabling the `@NotNull` validation?

Even more, if I want protect the **id** for the Address class:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    ...
    binder.setDisallowedFields("address.id");
}
```

The HTML code generated from the JSP file is

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Address:</legend>
    <table>
        <input id="address.id" name="address.id" type="hidden" value="5"/> 
        <tr>
            <td>Street:</td>
            <td><input id="address.street" name="address.street" type="text" value="" size="40"/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Number:</td>
            <td><input id="address.number" name="address.number" type="text" value="" size="40"/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

But again when I do the submit I get

```
- ValidationMessages found.
- org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages found.
- registerPerson POST
- Person [id=5, firstName=Manuel, lastName=Jordan, alive=true, dateBirth=Wed Dec 12 00:00:00 PET 2012, dateRetirement=null, dateDeath=null, age=15, weight=34.0, salary=1500]
- Address [id=null, street=La blanquita, number=155]
- There are errors!!!!
- Error Field error in object 'person' on field 'address.id': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.person.address.id,NotNull.address.id,NotNull.id,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [person.address.id,address.id]; arguments []; default message [address.id]]; default message [The field must be not empty]
```

If I am creating a new Person and using perhaps a special class giving a potential id (5 for example `address.setId("5");` in this case) for the Address's id it is going to be a problem.

**Second Question**: how I can turn around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating your model in the method with `GET`. Which means as soon as the page is rendered the model object is gone. When the `POST` comes in a new empty `Person` is created and due to automatic path expansion also an `Address` but this will not have the relationship correctly applied.

There are 2 ways to fix this.

1. Create a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` which constructs the model needed to use for binding.
2. Added `@SessionAttributes` to store the `Person` in the session in between requests.

Another thing to make either option work is next to `@Validated` you will need to add `@ModelAttribute` to your method `Person` method argument.

### Method with `@ModelAttribute`

First add the method which creates the model object. For this create a method and annotate it with `@ModelAttribute` and optionally give it a name of the model object `person`. (Which would also be the default, as that is to use the classname with a lowercase first letter).

```
@ModelAttribute("person")
public Person prepareModel() {
    Person person = new Person();
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setId("5");//just to play/test

    person.setAddress(address);
    address.setPerson(person);
    return person;
}
```

Next modify your GET and POST methods. First off all for both methods you can remove the `Model` as a method argument as that isn't needed anymore. The `Person` is already added to the model.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String createRegisterForm(){
    logger.info("createRegisterForm GET");
    return "jsp/person/registerForm";
}
```

And for the POST add `@ModelAttribute` and you don't need to

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerPerson( @Validated(PersonRegistrationOrdered.class) @ModelAttribute Person person, 
                              BindingResult result){
    logger.info("registerPerson POST");
    logger.info("{}", person.toString());
    logger.info("{}", person.getAddress().toString());

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        logger.error("There are errors!!!!");

        for(ObjectError objectError : result.getAllErrors()){
            logger.error("Error {}", objectError);
        }

        return "jsp/person/registerForm";
    }
    logger.info("All fine!!!!");
    return "jsp/manolo";
}
```

### Using `@SessionAttributes`

Using `@SessionAttributes` you can identify which objects to store, temporary, in the `HttpSession`. Add this annotation to your controller classes and in your POST method add `SessionStatus` as an argument and remove the `Model` as that will already be populated.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(Person.class)
public class RegisterController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/register.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerPerson( @Validated(PersonRegistrationOrdered.class) @ModelAttribute Person person, 
                                  BindingResult result, SessionStatus status){
        logger.info("registerPerson POST");
        logger.info("{}", person.toString());
        logger.info("{}", person.getAddress().toString());

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            logger.error("There are errors!!!!");

            for(ObjectError objectError : result.getAllErrors()){
                logger.error("Error {}", objectError);
            }

            return "jsp/person/registerForm";
        }
        logger.info("All fine!!!!");
        status.setComplete();
        return "jsp/manolo";
    }

}
```

You need to call the `setComplete()` method on the `SessionStatus` so that the session gets cleaned of obsolete model objects.

Comment: I think `@SessionAttributes` is better in the case we have multiple users creating a Person (different values for each case of course) in the same time.

Comment: That doesn't matter the `@ModelAttribute` is called before each request handling method. So each request gets a new/fresh instance of the `Person`.

Comment: True. BTW I am not creating a new method and using the `@ModelAttribute` according with your first suggestion, because when I do the submit (POST) it *calls* again the method with `@ModelAttribute`. Of course none value is overridden with the new empty Person object created, I am using the second option, @SessionAttributes and creating the object in the (GET) method and using the Model.addAttribute how I did from the beginning. All works fine. Thanks again

Comment: The method with `@ModelAttribute` is not called when the POST action happens, since the **person** object already exists in the *model*. Practically it works how a **Map**. Perfect

Comment: Well it is called i fyou don't use `@SessionAttributes` if you use `@SessionAttributes` it will first check the session to see if a model object with the given name (or type) already exists.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, `@ModelAttribute` is called when the POST is called **and** when the `@SessionAttributes` is not used, and none overridden happens for the model. Thanks again

Comment: Seems wise and good practice use `@ModelAttribute` for a GET and save it into the `@SessionAttributes` to be used in a POST.

Comment: For the audience, avoid `@SessionAttributes` in the case if the controller has the option to create and update the form Object, it is a huge problem if the user opens many tabs in the same browser